Multiple VLANs on a single interface and isolation
The issue I am facing is as follows:
I have a (hypothetical) switch in Physical Location 1, and another in Physical Location 2.
Physical Location 1 switch is connected to ISP (1gbe), nearby server A (1gbe) and the switch in Physical Location 2 (10gbe).
Physical Location 2 switch is connected to nearby server B (1gbe), nearby server C (1gbe) and the switch in Physical Location 1 (10gbe).
Switch 1 - Switch 2 connection is single Cat 6A copper.
What I want to achieve is that:

Server A and B must be able to access WAN
Server A must be able to access server C
Server B must not be able to access server C
Server C must be isolated from WAN

My initial idea to solve this obviously was based on setting up VLANs and routing between them - this would require both switches to be L3 switches, right?
So, how exactly would the configuration look like? This is my initial idea, but I lack the experience to validate it:

Switch 1 Interface 1 (VLAN 10) <-> Server A
Switch 1 Interface 2 (VLAN 20) <-> ISP Router
Switch 1 Interface 3 (VLAN 10,20,30) <-> Switch 2 Interface 1 (VLAN 10,20,30)
Switch 2 Interface 2 (VLAN 20) <-> Server B
Switch 2 Interface 3 (VLAN 30) <-> Server C
Routing on Switch 1: VLAN 10 <-> VLAN 20
Routing on Switch 1: VLAN 30 <-> VLAN 10

However, this doesn't solve the issue, as Server C isn't isolated from WAN, and I'm not sure if many VLANs are possible on a single interface. I would appreciate any guidance in this matter.
Edit:
Topology:
WAN - | ISP Router+NAT | -1g- | Switch 1 | -10g- | Switch 2 |
                                 |1g               |1g  |1g
                                 A                 B    C


Where is the router? Remember switches do not NAT, so unless you are only using public addressing, you need a router. If it is all public addressing, then one of the switches must be a layer-3 switch (has a router module) and you can use that to do what you want, otherwise do it on the router.

@RonMaupin Added network topology in the original post.

You will have a subinterface for each VLAN on the router, and you can do all the ACLs on the router, including blocking anything you want on the WAN interface, and allowing only traffic you want between the VLANs.


setting up VLANs and routing between them - this would require both switches to be L3 switches, right?

Either L3 switches or an additional router connected to the VLANs. If you use private addresses anywhere (firewall? DMZ? VPN?) then you need a NAT router. Also, you require firewalls if there's any communication with the Internet. A firewall can often be used as a VPN gateway as well.
Using L3 switches, you could use ACLs to limit connectivity between VLANs. Using a proper firewall, you'd set up policies to permit what you want and deny anything else.

I'm not sure if many VLANs are possible on a single interface

Business-grade switches and routers usually support dozens or even hundreds of VLANs.
For a more concrete answer you need to edit your question with a proposed topology of your network, showing VLANs, their connectivity, IP subnets and zoning.
